# preg_match only first occurence of numbers in pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am attempting to match the first occurrence of numbers in a pattern I have defined. The pattern is *adunit[numbers]*. So for example I can have a string that is *adunit23423*, or *adunit23*. The length of the numbers can vary.

My code so far:

```
$title = "*adunit54* testing this";
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $title, $matches);
$var = implode(' ', $matches[0]);
echo $var;
```

Which would output: 54

But if I were to change the string to "*adunit54* testing thi23s", the output would be changed to: 54 23

How do I make this expression get only the first set of numbers in my *adunit[number]* pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `preg_match` function which helps to do a single match where `preg_match_all` would do global match.

```
$title = "*adunit54* testing this";
preg_match('!\d+!', $title, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

If you still want to use preg_match_all then follow this trick.

```
preg_match_all('!^\D*\K\d+!', $title, $matches);
```

Comment: Ah makes sense, but is there anyway to incorporate my pattern as well into the pattern?

Comment: check my update... or `preg_match_all('!adunit\K\d+!', $title, $matches);`